# How to hide an extension's Browser Action icon programmatically in a popup.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

If we right click on an extension's Browser Action icon and choose `Hide button`,the icon will be hidden but the extension will still work.So can we make this programmatically? (with some javascript in the popup.html ?)

btw:I don't want using a page action instead of a browser action cuz the popup page provide some informations and hiding it or not should be decided by users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to programatically hide the browser action button.
There's a feature request to implement this feature through the [`chrome.management`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html) API, star it at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260281 if you want to get notified of updates.